# "newp" function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In an example I have found the function

```
net = newp([-2 2;-2 +2],1);
```

I have looked at the help for newp and it says:

```
       NET = newp(P,T,TF,LF) takes these inputs,
       P  - RxQ matrix of Q1 representative input vectors.
       T  - SxQ matrix of Q2 representative target vectors.
       TF - Transfer function, default = 'hardlim'.
       LF - Learning function, default = 'learnp'.
```

Does this mean that my perceptron has 2 inputs and it expects 1 as output? First it would send -2 and -2, expect to receive 1 and the sends 2, 2 and also expects 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your perceptron has one input which has two elements. Each input element has range [-2 2] since you specified same rows [-2 2] for the matrix P. There is one output. The second argument is the number of neurons.

You would use this by defining your input and target vectors. For this perceptron your input would be 2xN element matrix where N is the number inputs with each input having two elements. Your output would be an N element vector.

Example,

```
P = [0 0 1 1; 0 1 0 1];
T = [0 0 0 1];
net = newp([-2 2;-2 +2],1);
net = train(net,P,T);
Y = net(P)
```